# Gspread. Move to next column for cell entry if first column is full. How can I do this?

Tags: python-3.x, gspread

When column A fills up, I want to move to B. I'm able to enter in either A or B but I can't switch between the two if one fails.

Edit: I've determined that the code works when there's no try/except thrown at it.

```
def next_available_row(wks):
    try:
        str_list2 = list(filter(None, wks.col_values(1, 2)))
        return str(len(str_list2)+1)
    except:
        str_list2 = list(filter(None, wks.col_values(2, 1)))
        return str(len(str_list2)+1)
##        try:
##            wks.update_acell("A{}".format(next_row), tInput3)
##        except:
        wks.update_acell("B{}".format(next_row), tInput3)
```

So if I block out column A, column B will populate properly. What gives? :|

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  ugly but it works.

```
def next_available_row(wks):
    try:
        str_list2 = list(filter(None, wks.col_values(1, 2)))
        return str(len(str_list2)+1)
    except:
        print("unable to do 'A'")

def next_available_rowB(wks):        
    try:
        str_list2 = list(filter(None, wks.col_values(2, 1)))
        return str(len(str_list2)+1)
    except:
        print("unable to do 'B'")



        try:
            wks.update_acell("A{}".format(next_row), tInput3)
        except:
            wks.update_acell("B{}".format(next_rowB), tInput3)
```